# $\inf(A+B) \geq \inf(A)+\inf(B)$, proving inequality holds?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

We have.... $x \in A + B ⇒ x = a + b, a \in A, b \in B$
We know that  $a \geq \inf(A)$ and $b \geq \inf(B)$.
Hence, $x \geq \inf(A)+\inf(B) ⇒ \inf(A+B) \geq \inf(A)+\inf(B)$

I made the proof this far and now I am trying to find an examples of where the strict inequality holds.

So If I set $A = \{0,1\}$ and $B = \{1,0\}$ ..Then $A+B = \{1,1\}$
Which doesn't work.

How would you prove the inequality holds?

Could you do set $A = \{0,2\}$ and set $B = \{2,0\}...A+B = \{2,2\}$

$\inf(A+B) = 2 > \inf(A) + \inf(B)$?

But im not sure this is the way to go about it?

Comment: in your last example, $A+B=\{0,2\}$ not $\{2,2\}$ (because $0+0=0$).

Comment: No, you must have equality. Take a sequence in A converging to infA and a sequence in B converging to infB. The sum converges to infA+infB.

Comment: Actually in this case it is $A+B = \{0,2,4\}$ in the last example.

Comment: @LeBtz Yes :P I forgot the well-known fact that $2+2=4$..

Answer (score 1):

For **sets** $A,B\subset\mathbb R$ we actually always have $\inf(A+B) = \inf A+\inf B$.

It is other circumstances where we have an inequality, for example when we are looking at **functions** $f,g:X\to\mathbb R$, then we have $$\inf_{x\in X}(f(x)+g(x))\geq \inf_{x\in X}f(x)+\inf_{x\in X}g(x).$$

You can find a strict inequality here with $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto \operatorname{sgn}(x)$ and $g := -f$ for example.

Comment: Yea, but im looking for a set such as {2,2} or {0,2} to work.

Comment: This is also in my answer. You won't find any because we have equality for sets.

Comment: but if you were looking at sup, say, you could have a set {0,1} and {1,0} hold with the inequality sup(A+B) <= sup(A) + sup(B)

Comment: For suprema we also have equality always if you are looking at sets. Do you realize that $\{0,1\} = \{1, 0\}$?

Answer (score 1):

The strict inequality never holds, in fact, we have $\inf(A+B)=\inf A+\inf B.$ Let's prove this as follows: Let $r>0$ be given. Then there are $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $a<\inf A+r$ and $b<\inf B+r$ so $a+b<\inf A+\inf B+2r$ but $\inf(A+B)\leqslant a+b$ so $\inf(A+B)<\inf A+\inf B+2r$ and since $r$ is arbitrary then $\inf(A+B)\leqslant\inf A+\inf B$